# raspbian and raspberry pi 3B+

Tags: raspbian, pi-3b+, i2c

does raspberry pi raspbian had inbuilt I2C driver? or does that depend on the pi board? I am using raspbian as a OS in Raspberry 3B+. but the thing is whenever I run the code it will either show that you doesn't have SMbus2 or "fcntl" module even if I installed those module or library successfully before running the code on Raspberry pi. if you have a solution than it will be big help.

Comment: SMbus2? ???????

Comment: yes it has all the i2c library which doesn't work for windows os or linux library but it has to work for raspbian because pi has i2c module

Answer (score 1):

I got my answer I did a silly mistake I forgot to enable the i2c module of raspberry pi form raspbian configuration.